# Why can't I extract data from media file using AVURLAsset in a Playground?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, swift-playground, avurlasset

In my Playground:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var path2 = "/Users/me/Movies/bukesiyi.mp4"
var video2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path2, isDirectory: false)
// it shows: file:///Users/me/Movies/bukesiyi.mp4
video2.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil)
// it's true
var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: video2)
// it shows: <AVURLAsset: 0x7fc0a9f13500, URL = file:///Users/me/Movies/bukesiyi.mp4>
asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
// it's []
asset.readable
// it's false
asset.playable
// it's false
asset.commonMetadata
// it's []
```

I don't know what is wrong, maybe the path? The documentation is not clear.

Comment: Have you tried the same thing from a command-line project? Playgrounds have funny rules about accessing the filesystem. I believe that to access a resource file you need to import it into the playground's Resources folder, otherwise it will be inaccessible. It is odd to me that it comes back as "reachable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because Playgrounds are [sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html).

Although you can see your file URL with `.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError`, you can't actually access the filesystem from a Playground.

**The solution is to embed the file in the Playground itself.**

Open the File Navigator (with menu or CMD+1) then *drop* your MP4 file in the navigator's *Resources* folder.

When done, you can access the file with `NSBundle` - or even just drag and drop the file from the navigator to the Playground:

```
let video2 = #
```

and drop the file where I've put the #, it will paste an icon which is actually the file URL.

Now this URL will work with your code.

[image]

Comment: It's OK for me. Thanks very much!