# Not able to read file in a Playground

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager, file-handling

I am trying to read data.txt file with the help of playground. But it is returning nil.
First I instantiated `NSFileManager` object. Than used the function `fileExistsAtPath` it is returning true.
After instantiating `NSFileHandle` it is returning nil.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit



var defaultManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if defaultManager.fileExistsAtPath("/Users/toshishakhand/Documents/data.txt") {
  print("File exists") // output : File Exists
} else {
  print("File not found")
}

var fileHandler: NSFileHandle ? = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "/Users/toshishakhand/Documents/data.txt")


if fileHandler == nil {
  print("File open failed") //output : nil
} else {
  print("File does not exist")
}
```

Comment: the playground is sandboxed, you cannot access files outside of it.

Comment: Playground are sandboxed. You have to embed the file in the Playground. You can take example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616197/why-cant-i-extract-data-from-media-file-using-avurlasset-in-a-playground/34617041#34617041

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33404160/2303865

Comment: put the file at your resource folder and use NSBundle URLForResource or pathForResource

Comment: @EricD Thanks for quick replay. I added the file to my resource folder. Now how to specify path?

Comment: You can then drop the file *from* the Resources folder *to* the Playground in your code, it will automatically make an NSURL to the file. Otherwise you can use NSBundle.

Comment: More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31840630/2227743 for NSBundle.

Comment: Thanks. I am not getting `NSFileManager` worked properly.Why it did't showed any error

Comment: Oh sorry Nishant I didn't notice this comment of yours earlier. Is it working now?

Comment: ya it is working fine. Thanks. But can you tell me why NSFileManger Logic is returning true i.e the file exist.  It should also not work because Playground is sandboxed. :)